# How to get network into protein shape in cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape, protein-database

I have a protein network loaded into cytoscape.
I want to get the network nodes into a shape that corresponds that of the protein shape/structure. 
This is so that I can superimpose the network image onto the protein structure image.
I tried RINanalyzer and structureviz2, but it didn't help. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more specific about what didn't work with RINalyzer and structureViz2?  The layout provided by RINalyzer usually does a pretty good job for me.

-- scooter

Comment: I want the nodes in the network to be at the position of the corresponding residues in the protein

Comment: In the latest version of RINalyzer there is a new Layout (RINlayout).  Run that layout after you have created the RIN and it should move the residues to approximately the right place.